# How to configure routes.rb for get access to localhost:3000/admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I follow the tutorial of active_admin at this url: [activeadmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)

I tried to add it to a project that already exists followings this differents steps:

- Add it to my Gemfile `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`
- Run the follow command because i already install devise `rails g active_admin:install --skip-users`
- And `rake db:migrate && rails server`

My problem is that when i want to access to localhost:3000/admin i get this error `Unknown Action AbstractController::ActionNotFound`

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  config[:controllers][:sessions] = 'sessions'
  config[:controllers][:registrations] = 'registrations'
  config[:as] = 'admin'

  devise_for :users, config

  # Login / Logout routes
  namespace :v1, path: '/' do
    devise_scope :user do
      post '/sessions', to: 'sessions#create'
      post '/registrations', to: 'registrations#create'
      delete '/sessions', to: 'sessions#destroy'
    end

    # User routes
    get '/user', to: 'users#show'
    patch '/user/update', to: 'users#update'
  end
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

I'm using rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.2.2

UPDATE 09/06
`rake routes`

```
    new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                    sessions#new
        admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                    sessions#create
destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                   sessions#destroy
       admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#create
   new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)             active_admin/devise/passwords#new
  edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                           PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                           PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
cancel_admin_user_registration GET        /admin/cancel(.:format)                   registrations#cancel
   admin_user_registration POST       /admin(.:format)                          registrations#create
   new_admin_user_registration GET        /admin/sign_up(.:format)                  registrations#new
   edit_admin_user_registration GET        /admin/edit(.:format)                     registrations#edit
                           PATCH      /admin(.:format)                          registrations#update
                           PUT        /admin(.:format)                          registrations#update
                           DELETE     /admin(.:format)                          registrations#destroy
               v1_sessions POST       /sessions(.:format)                       v1/sessions#create
          v1_registrations POST       /registrations(.:format)                  v1/registrations#create
                           DELETE     /sessions(.:format)                       v1/sessions#destroy
                   v1_user GET        /user(.:format)                           v1/users#show
            v1_user_update PATCH      /user/update(.:format)                    v1/users#update
                admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                          admin/dashboard#index
           admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format) admin/admin_users#batch_action
         admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#index
                           POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#create
      new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)          admin/admin_users#new
     edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/admin_users#edit
          admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#show
                           PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                           PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                           DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#destroy
            admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#index
                           POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#create
             admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)             admin/comments#show
```

and the log

```
  F, [2015-06-09T10:45:02.609120 #2451] FATAL -- : 
  AbstractController::ActionNotFound (AbstractController::ActionNotFound):
  /home/snoobie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0b4b22871fd3/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:29:in `only_render_implemented_actions'
```

I hope someone can explain me what i'm doing wrong.
Thank you !

Comment: What do you get when you run `rake routes`?

Comment: I add an update to my post

Comment: Maybe the default activeadmin link (/admin) is conflicting with devise. You should probably take a look at this link [https://gist.github.com/mikeatlas/5628317](https://gist.github.com/mikeatlas/5628317).

Comment: Thank you @juliobetta i took a look to the link and change my routes, but nothing change. If i create a new rails project and add the activeadmin gem that works, otherwise for an old project i get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin), more easly to agregate to the project. If someone need more informations about the process to add [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) in rails project. Please let a comment and i will explain it in details.